# Why G1 Garbage collector is called "Garbage First"?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

While I am reading Oracle's [documentation on G1 Garbage Collector](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/tutorials/tutorials-1876574.html#t2), I noted following -

> When performing garbage collections, G1 operates in a manner similar to the CMS collector. G1 performs a concurrent global marking phase to determine the liveness of objects throughout the heap. After the mark phase completes, **G1 knows which regions are mostly empty**. It collects in these regions first, which usually yields a large amount of free space. **This is why this method of garbage collection is called Garbage-First**

As mentioned in above quote, G1 selects the regions which are mostly empty.

My question is, if any region is mostly empty, how would that yields large amount of free memory ? If it is mostly empty, it is already a part of free memory. Isn't it ?

Could anyone here help me clarify this ?

Answer (score 2):

In this sentence:

> After the mark phase completes, G1 knows which regions are mostly empty.

"mostly empty" means "contains the most reclaimable garbage".  This is clear from the context.  The purpose of the mark phase is to determine which objects are definitely or probably reachable.  The rest are definitely unreachable, and can be collected.

Collecting regions with the largest amount of reclaimable space is good for two reasons:

1. You get the most space back soonest.
2. With a copying collector, there is less work to do if the "from" space mostly contains stuff that you don't need to copy to the "to" space.  So you get the most space back efficiently.

In most use-cases, the 2nd reason is more significant.  It is rarely important to get space back quickly.  You just need the space to be available when the application requests it.  (GC pauses are a different matter, but they are caused by other things.)

Answer (score 0):

Think of of "garbage first" as a shorthand for "most garbage-y first." That is, it defines various blocks of memories, and then prioritizes the ones with the most garbage -- thus getting the most bang for its buck.

From the page you cited:

> **G1 concentrates** its collection and compaction activity **on** the areas of the heap that are likely to be full of reclaimable objects, that is, **garbage**. *(emphasis added)*

... as opposed to just treating every block of memory as equally-good for GC, even if 99% of it contains live objects.